# What would cause 'fdt: not creating '/sys/firmware/fdt': CRC check failed' during boot?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, u-boot

I am booting a pre-built FIT image from a vendor's SDK (NXP SDK2.0) on an ARM reference platform (ls1046ardb).  This .itb image contains 'kernel@1', 'fdt@1', and 'ramdisk@1'.

During boot I see a CRC check failure on the FDT.  Is this failure common and expected?  Although it's always possible, I wouldn't expect a vendor's pre-built images to be corrupted.

```
[    3.600660] fsl_generic: FSL DPAA Generic Ethernet driver
[    3.606246] rtc-pcf2127 1-0051: pcf2127_get_datetime: read error
[    3.612256] rtc-pcf2127 1-0051: hctosys: unable to read the hardware clock
[    3.619213] fdt: not creating '/sys/firmware/fdt': CRC check failed
[    3.625868] RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
[    4.508215] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) readonly on device 1:0.
[    4.514883] devtmpfs: mounted
```

The boot command (from u-boot) is,

```
kernel_load=0xa0000000
ext2load mmc 0 $kernel_load kernel.itb
bootm $kernel_load
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I don't see many references to this type of error on the net.